# Flash Platformer Game changing between two characters

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I'm new to coding as a whole and though I've messed a little with AS before I'm at an absolute loss. I've been using a [pretty helpful website](http://as3gametuts.com/) that gives a step-by-step on making a platformer/sidescroller, but one of the key things I want to include in my game is the ability to swap between two characters- i.e., if the player hit space or any other key, you could swap out to the other character (with different abilities and all).

My game only really has one big stage, and it's nothing complicated at all (it's something I'm trying to get done in about a little over 24 hours) which is why I decided not to make the character change for each "level"- because there's only one big one. I want the player to be able to decide when they want to play whichever character they fancy, but I have no idea how to go about it.

Uh, and if it helps clarify anything, I basically tried to follow that tutorial site as closely as I could without copying source code.

Thanks so much for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a thing named "separate graphics from code". The tutorial says "convert your player to a Movie Clip Symbol ... create new Player(), add it to stage", then it teaches about how to control the player. You need to split your `Player` class into two, one remains as `Player` and contains code, the other is a skin class, barely a MovieClip without code. In your `Player` class you need to make a method to operate skins, the interface is up to you, I suggest a string lookup of a skin class, then you can tell your player to change skins both at costruction time and probably at runtime. An example:

```
public static const SKIN_DEFAULT:String="default";
public static const SKIN_RED:String="red";
public static const SKIN_BLUE:String="blue";
private static var SKINS:Object={
    SKIN_DEFAULT:DefaultFace;
    SKIN_RED:RedFace;
    SKIN_BLUE:BlueFace;
}
```

Here, `SKINS` is a lookup object with keys as strings and value as `Class` references, these are the MovieClip symbol names an example expects to exist. Say you want a gray blob, a red angry face and a blue smiley save to be available, you name them `DefaultFace`, `RedFace`, `BlueFace` and put these names into this lookup object. Then, you need to make your player change skins. It's pretty easy once you get the drill.

```
public class Player extends Sprite {
    // Sprite should do, as Player is now code-only
    private var skin:MovieClip; // this will hold our player's skin
    public function setSkin(newSkin:String):void {
        // call this to change the skin
        var newSkin:Class=SKINS[newSkin] as Class;
        if (newSkin==null) return; // sanity check
        if (skin) if (skin is newSkin) return; 
        // ^ changing skin for the same? We're that skin already!
        if (skin) if (contains(skin)) removeChild(skin); // remove old skin
        skin=new newSkin(); // create a new skin object
        addChild(skin); // make it attached to the player
    } // we're done!
    // rest of code here
}
```

Make sure that your `Player` will at least put on default skin when created, or else you won't be able to see player move.

In order to trigger skin change, you can create an array of buttons, up to making them out of all possible `SKINS` (for this, either expose `SKINS` variable by declaring it `public` instead of private as it's now, or provide another means to get the list of classes), which will call `player.setSkin()` with a correct parameter.

Comment: I see, so a skin class would change the way the character looks. Thank you so much for responding, this actually gives me a lot insight about  how exactly this works (I kinda just went with the flow), but I was hoping to have two characters that act differently, not just look different. I.e. one of them can do something the other cannot, which is why I want to do this character changing so bad. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, you put all functionality in `Player` class, then you just check what new abilities should the player be able to do when applying new skin.